# $SU(2) \otimes SU(2)$ and Compact Matrix Quantum Groups

Tags: quantum-groups

$SU_{\mu}(2)$ (where $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$) is an example of a compact matrix quantum group, as defined by Woronowicz, but is $SU(2) \otimes SU(2) = Spin (4)$ also a compact matrix quantum group?

Comment: Well, I am not sure, what do you mean by your question. Since it is in particular a compact matrix group, it must then be also a compact matrix quantum group.